# unsubscribed (Action Cable) don't execute exactly when its called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, actioncable

So I'm building a chat, in the page of the chat, there's this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      chatChannel?.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

That is suposed to call this code in backend

```
  def unsubscribed
    ConnectedList.remove({id: connection.user.id, channel: stream_channel})
    stop_stream_for stream_channel
  end
```

It works, but not at right time, I mean the backend won't immediately unsubscribed the user from the channel as solicited, it will take a long time as execute a lot of unsubscribe solicitations
together.

May someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I was trying to make subscription in a function and then calling it in useEffect, when I should do something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const chatChannel = cable?.subscriptions?.create(
      {
        channel: 'TransferMessagesChannel',
        room: transfer?.id as number,
      },
      {
        received(message: TransferMessage) {
          handleReceivedMessage(message);
        },
      }
    );

    setChatChannel(chatChannel);

    return () => {
      chatChannel?.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```